# Flutter TextField value always null on ios device?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am currently testing my Flutter app on both my iPhone 8 and my Android moto G8.

However, the issue I am running into is that while everything works well on my Android moto G8, on my iPhone it seems that whenever I change a TextField the value in the previous TextField becomes null i.e.:

```
flutter: This is in error: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 174 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true.
```

But When I was typing on the device the printout is:

```
flutter: This is in email:test@gmail.com, value: test@gmail.com
```

Here is the code for my custom textfield:

```
class InputTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  InputTextFields({this.title, this.obscureText, this.setValue});

  final String title;
  final bool obscureText;
  Function setValue;

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  _InputTextFieldsState createState() => _InputTextFieldsState();
}

class _InputTextFieldsState extends State<InputTextFields> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String hintText;
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 35, right: 35),
  child: TextField(
    obscureText: widget.obscureText,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.title,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.grey),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      hintText: hintText,
    ),
    onChanged: widget.setValue,
  ),
);
}
 }
```

So I am sure the TextField is working as intended but the error still persists. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be from your `onChanged: widget.setValue` in your `TextField`. Your function is making the previous TextField null. The best way to retrieve the value of a `TextField` is to use a `TextEditingController`. In order to use a `TextEditingController` in your custom TextField, you would have to pass it as a parameter.

```
class InputTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  InputTextFields({this.title, this.obscureText, this.controller});
  final String title;
  final bool obscureText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
}
```

In your TextField:

```
controller:widget.controller
```

This is how you use that new custom TextField:

```
final TextEditingController myController=TextEditingController();
InputTextFields(title:"Test",obscureText:false,controller:myController),
```

I think you are trying to validate if the TextField's value is an email or not. You could easily check it by using RegExp or by using https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator package. You could also use TextFormField instead of TextField to check if the TextField's value is null. Have a look at this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your suggestion. But with what I have it works on physical Android device, simulation iOS devices, and on physical iOS (other views). So I am not so sure if that is exactly the problem

Comment: that seems to be the problem to me. Try my solution out if it works. It really isn't good to run a function every time the value of a TextField changes.